# putExtra to Service class stops when app is closed

Tags: java, android, service, background-service

I am new to java, I have one Activity named  **LaunchApp.class** and one Service named **MyService.class** in AndroidStudio. I made the app in such a way that when the app is totally closed or swiped away, the service should continue functioning well in background. I send a variable from **LaunchApp.class** to **MyService.class** through `putExtra` method as below:

```
// In  LaunchApp.class under onCreate method    
Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchApp.this,MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("myVar",loginName.getText().toString());
startService(intent);
```

Then I receive this in Service.class as the below code:

```
//under onStartCommand method
String sessionVar = intent.getStringExtra("myVar");
Toast.makeText(MyService.this, sessionVar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The code works perfectly and I receive that "myVar" string. but when the app is closed or swiped away from the screen, the variable stops and causes the app to crash. And I think the reason is this way of passing the variable from that Activity to the Service because if I try using local string variable in MyService.class the app functions well even after totally closing it. Please help on this.

Comment: can you put the crash log？

Comment: The crash log gives me this message: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service staryte.com.sTaryte.TimerService@af00c57 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after searching in different sources.. in order to continue getting the value of the variable  in Service even after killing the app, you need to use

```
return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
```

instead of using

```
return START_STICKY;
```

in onStartCommand. Thanks!